# BundlerMinifier Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

We are trying to install the NuGet Package for the BundlerMinifier in VS2022, but we get no context menu or nothing to allow us to minify or bundle or anything else for that matter.

Is this a known issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue which is also described on the Github page of the package:
https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/585

The solution for me was to install it from VS marketplace:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Failwyn.BundlerMinifier64

And now I can bundle again even in VS2022